# Consider defining a bean of type 'net.corda.core.messaging.CordaRPCOps' in your configuration

Tags: spring, webserver, corda

Unable to use CordaRPCOps implementation methods in my CustomController,

```
@RequestMapping(value="/peers", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Map<String, List<String>> peers() throws Exception
    {

        CordaRPCOps proxy=rpc.getParameterValue("proxy");

        Party myIdentity= proxy.nodeInfo().getLegalIdentities().get(0);

        return ImmutableMap.of("peers", rpcOpsImpl.networkMapSnapshot()
                .stream()
                .filter(nodeInfo -> nodeInfo.getLegalIdentities().get(0) != myIdentity)
                .map(it -> it.getLegalIdentities().get(0).getName().getOrganisation())
                .collect(toList()));
        }
```

getting error while building runPartyAServer as,

```
APPLICATION FAILED TO START

Description:

Field services in net.corda.server.controllers.CustomController required a bean of type 'net.corda.core.messaging.CordaRPCOps' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'net.corda.core.messaging.CordaRPCOps' in your configuration.
```

Comment: Can you get code to show where the `rpc` variable is instantiated?

Comment: @Controller
public class CustomController {

    private NodeRPCConnection rpc;
 private  CordaRPCOps rpcOpsImpl;
 }

getting proxy value from NodeRPCConnection using,
CordaRPCOps proxy=rpc.getParameterValue("proxy");

Comment: can anyone help me regarding this exception

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, you must define a bean of type CordaRPCConnection/CordaRPCOps.

Something similar to:

```
@Bean
private fun connect(): CordaRPCConnection {
    val hostAndPort = NetworkHostAndPort(configuration.host, configuration.port)
    val client = CordaRPCClient(hostAndPort)
    val connection = client.start(configuration.user, configuration.password)
    return connection;
}
```

We do not provide any DI container integration by default.

Comment: My problem is not with rpc variable, I am unable to use rpcOps variable while using CordaRPCops methods , this is my variable deceleration                     
 private  CordaRPCOps rpcOps;  in my custom controller, getting error as,                  Field services in net.corda.server.controllers.CustomController required a bean of type 'net.corda.core.messaging.CordaRPCOps' that could not be found.

Comment: I have imported required one, import net.corda.core.messaging.CordaRPCOps;

Comment: Could you please use the correct formatting for your code blocks. It is impossible to see what is going on.

You are missing the point. Spring is telling you that there is no Bean defined. See above to see how to add a new bean.